# Controlled non UI timer in metro app (.NET)

Tags: .net, timer, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I need a timer class which should provide functionality to start/stop/enable/disable and should be NON UI.

I see 2 options

1. [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer) -> has all functionality except  that it is executed on UI thread
2. [ThreadPoolTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.threading.threadpooltimer) -> No control over periodic timer.

I was thinking of creating wrapper over threadpool timer, but seems very complex as no/limited control over it.

How to design a timer class for the stated sceneario. (I require something similar to System.Threading.Timer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the UI should be very responsive in Metro apps - it might be enough to run a DispatcherTimer and call Task.Run() on things you want run on background thread.

If that does not work for you - see if this does. It should have a similar API to the DispatcherTimer, but run on a different thread. Not that it keeps waiting for exactly the duration of the Interval set, so the timer will be notoriously late. It is also not exactly thread safe and I only played with it for 10 minutes, so it might not always work, but since it is open source - you can modify it to fit your bill.

```
public class BackgroundTimer
{
    private AutoResetEvent _stopRequestEvent;
    private AutoResetEvent _stoppedEvent;

    #region Interval
    private TimeSpan _interval;
    public TimeSpan Interval
    {
        get
        {
            return _interval;
        }
        set
        {
            if (IsEnabled)
            {
                Stop();
                _interval = value;
                Start();
            }
            else
            {
                _interval = value;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    public event EventHandler<object> Tick;

    #region IsEnabled
    private bool _isEnabled;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _isEnabled;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isEnabled == value)
                return;

            if (value)
                Start();
            else
                Stop();
        }
    } 
    #endregion

    public BackgroundTimer()
    {
        _stopRequestEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _stoppedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (_isEnabled)
        {
            return;
        }

        _isEnabled = true;
        _stopRequestEvent.Reset();
        Task.Run((Action)Run);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (!_isEnabled)
        {
            return;
        }

        _isEnabled = false;
        _stopRequestEvent.Set();
        _stoppedEvent.WaitOne();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        while (_isEnabled)
        {
            _stopRequestEvent.WaitOne(_interval);

            if (_isEnabled &&
                Tick != null)
            {
                Tick(this, null);
            }
        }

        _stoppedEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for nice implementation. 
I will use this, and update if needed. But most of the foundation work is already done. 
Thread safety/Synchronization seems to be the only concern.

Comment: Cool. BTW - I added it to the WinRT XAML Toolkit (http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit) together with a sample and made it somewhat adjust the intervals, so that the average Tick frequency is closer to what the Interval value would indicate. It actually seems to be more precise than the DispatcherTimer even without these adjustments.

Comment: there exist WinRTXamlToolKit and i was not aware. Thanks for sharing and if you have some pending items/ideas, i would be happy be contribute.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a clock with the following code:

```
ThreadPoolTimer Timer1 = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(Timer1_ElapsedHandler, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
clockTick = false;
UpdateLoop();
```

For this you need an event handler, in my clock this set that the timer ticked:

```
public void Timer1_ElapsedHandler(ThreadPoolTimer timer)
{
    clockTick = true;
}
```

Then to update the GUI (or whatever you need), there is an update loop:

```
public async void UpdateLoop()
{
    do
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    } while (!clockTick);
    ClockTextBlock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    clockTick = false;
    UpdateLoop();
}
```

Probably wrapping this in a class and cleaning it up a bit may give you the fundation for a good non UI timer.